# Cannot delete orphaned domain contorller

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003

One of the main domain controllers harddisk failed so I had to replace it and reinstall Windows Server 2003 all over again from scratch. Luckily, I have another domain controller layer around.

Now the problem is that I could join the domain because of "The specified user already exists". I went to *AC Users and Computers* on the other domain controller to delete the old computer name but I received "The object SER1 (or some of the objects it contains) cannot be deleted because: **Access is denied**" note that I logged in with a Enterprise admin privileges. This is really weird.

Did some internet searching and found that I have to delete the old name using ADSI Edit (adsiedit.msc) but to no avail. I still get Access is denied.

Kindly advice. I am really getting frustrated and I need to use the same old name on the server.

Thanks in advance
SZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to go thru the [Forcing the Removal of a Domain Controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781245(WS.10).aspx) procedure as specified by Microsoft. You can't just delete the old computer object and have things work properly.

You can't do the "dcpromo /forceremoval" portion because the old computer is already gone, so just ignore that part.

The only part you'll really need to do is the [NTDS metadata cleanup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736378(WS.10).aspx) portion of the procedure, so you might just skip to that.

Comment: Thanks but the forcing removal did not work. I don't know what is the source if the problem here.

I even tried running this vbs script http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/ad/domains/addmvb04.mspx?mfr=true

and while it shows it's a successful process I still see the old domain controller

Comment: What do you mean by "the forcing removal did not work"? Are you receiving an error message when attempt to do the metadata cleanup from NTDSUTIL?

Comment: I didnt know how to use "metadata cleanup". Sorry if i miss informed you earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Petri.co.il has excellent guides for this.

http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm

http://www.petri.co.il/forcibly_removing_active_directoy_from_dc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Remove the replication link for the server in AD sites and services. Problem fixed. Try deleting again.

Comment: Can you add more explanation of how and why this fixes the problem.